# How to use apscheduler to trigger job at specific times?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am using python apscheduler module to trigger job at irregular intervals for example at 1:30 AM and 11:10 PM on every day, but not able to find a solution to this.

Could you please help me how to do it. I don't want to create two jobs, one for 1:30 AM and 11:10 PM. At least let me know how to do it with crontab so that I will do same with apscheduler. Thanks.

I went through this link https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/v2.1.2/cronschedule.html#available-fields but not getting an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you want to create two jobs? What's wrong with it?

Comment: maintainance will be problem. For example if the user want to stop then he has to stop two jobs. Consider if there are 10 irregular intervals then will be a big problem and also tracking the status of each job also a problem.

Comment: link in your question seems dead

Answer (score 8, accepted):

APScheduler 3.5.0, due for release shortly, should cover this case:

```
from apscheduler.triggers.multi import OrTrigger

trigger = OrTrigger([CronTrigger(hour=1, minute=30), CronTrigger(hour=23, minute=10)]
scheduler.add_job(yourfunc, trigger)
```

Comment: Update: `from apscheduler.triggers.combining import OrTrigger`